# Android.App.Application class being set to null

Tags: null, xamarin, android

I am coding a Xamarin application, and I have some questions in regards to using the `Android.App.Application` class.

1. Am I correct in saying that the objects in the
   `Android.App.Application` class can sometimes be reset to null?
2. When/why does this happen?
3. How can I get my application to perform this occurrence so that I
   can test for this eventuality?

Will the following code be sufficient in case this does happen?

```
public class MyApplication : Android.App.Application 
{
    public static WebServiceData1_0 webServiceData;

    public static void SetupObjects()
    {
        webServiceData = new WebServiceData1_0();
    }

    public static WebServiceData1_0 GetWebServiceData()
    {
        if (webServiceData == null)
        {
            webServiceData = new WebServiceData1_0();
        }
        return webServiceData;
    }
}
```

In the above code, each time I wish to use the `WebServiceData1_0` object, I should use the `GetWebServiceData()` function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The getter method should do it, but it's not thread safe. As long as you are only calling it from the main thread you are safe. But I'd use double checked locking or some other pattern to make it thread safe.

Comment: I am calling the Android.App.Application from multiple activities. Does this pose a problem?

Comment: No, only if you call the getter from another thread, e.g. IntentService or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sort of. When application instance is destroyed it means that OS removed your entire application and next time user clicks on it (or otherwise starts it) it will be created again.
2. Se above.
3. Just make sure you initialize your stuff when Application starts (perhaps by overriding Application.OnCreate) and you could also consider Lazy for deferred initialization if it takes time.

Comment: So the only time that data can be removed from the application class is when the whole application stops? The values will not just randomly be reset to null during program execution. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. That goes to static members as well regardless where they are declared (actually that's your case and not the Application instance data).